# convert table image to excel using python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I have an image which is in the table-like structure as shown below:
[image]

Now I want to convert the image content to excel (exactly as in image as each separate cells)using python

Comment: did you find a way to solve this.

Comment: @Jag99 you can use detectron for detection